# Gridview, Update function affecting all rows instead of single row

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

For my programming class, I just started using GridView for a movie database table and now I am implementing a edit, update and delete function. I got the edit and update to work but the Update is giving me trouble.

When I click update all my rows are updated to the same thing (Example: I edit movie title and all rows are changed to the same movie title). I'm unsure if I got my labeling mixed up somewhere.

My Database Table:
[image]
**Note:** I am also the code I am using is an example from class and the one from class works but for some reason mine doesn't.

Below is my code sample.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="MovieResults" Wrap="true" Visible="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        OnRowEditing="btnSubmit_Click_one" OnRowUpdating="btnSubmit_update_record"
        DataKeyNames="MovieID" OnRowDeleting="btnSubmit_delete_record">
        <Columns>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="MovieTitle" HeaderText="Movie" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateChecked" HeaderText="Date Checked" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CheckedOut" HeaderText="Checked Out" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MovieDescription" HeaderText="Description" />
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ImageLocation" ControlStyle-Width="50"
                ControlStyle-Height = "50" HeaderText = "Movie Image" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

cs file

```
public void btnSubmit_update_record(Object Src, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        get_connection();
        try
        {
            int id = int.Parse(MovieResults.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            connection.Open();

            command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE content SET MovieTitle=@MovieTitle, MovieDescription=@MovieDescription WHERE TRUE", connection);

            //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovieID",
                          //((TextBox)MovieResults.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text.ToString());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovieTitle",
                ((TextBox)MovieResults.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text.ToString());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovieDescription",
                ((TextBox)MovieResults.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text.ToString());

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            // Handle an error by displaying the information.
            lblInfo.Text = "Error reading the database. ";
            lblInfo.Text += err.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Either way, make sure the connection is properly closed.
            // (Even if the connection wasn't opened successfully,
            //  calling Close() won't cause an error.)
            connection.Close();
            lblInfo.Text += "<br /><b>Update was successfull</b> ";
            lblInfo.Text += connection.State.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at the `WHERE` clause in your update query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some code in your `RowUpdating` event. You must databind the grid after an update or delete or edit operation else your grid will not show the correct data.

So, let us assume you have a method that gets the data for your gridview and it's called `GetMoviesData()`. Then, at the end of your `btnSubmit_update_record` method you will have to include following code.

```
MovieResults.EditIndex = -1;
MovieResults.DataSource = GetMoviesData();
MovieResults.DataBind();
```